# Select multiple but not all (e.g. //*) tag names via XPath?

Tags: html, css, xml, selenium, xpath

I am running automation on a webpage that has a lot of elements in the form:

```
<label ...>"label name"</label>
<div ...></div>
```

And I need to click the `<div>` element. I have a function that locates it using the xpath:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(text(),'value')]/following-sibling::div"))
```

However, some of the element have a slight different form. E.g., one is in the form:

```
<label ...>"label name"</label>
<br ...></br>
<input ...></input>
```

And I need to click the `<input>` element. I can't just use `/following-sibling::*` because the `<br>` element is the following sibling.

I could easily just write another function using `<input>` but I would prefer to just update and reuse the function I already have (and I'm curious). Is there any way to specify an element can have one of multiple tag names?

Maybe something like: `/following-sibling::[div or input]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//label[.='l1']/following-sibling::*[self::div or self::input]
```

will select all `div` or `input` sibling elements following a `label` element with a string value of `l1`.